# "By this time next week, I" + "will have worked" or "will work"?

Tags: future-tense, future-perfect

> 1. By this time next week, I ***will have worked*** on this project for twenty days.
> 2. By this time next week, I ***will work*** on this project for twenty days.

Do they both mean the same? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if the project won't have been finished by this time next week, and you will continue to work on it, you say: By this time next week, I will have been working on this project for twenty days.